# Have to work with object which has Set of enties using Java 8?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I have to implement method with the following signature:

```
public Set<Event> getForDateRange(Calendar from, Calendar to)
```

My `Event` class looks like:

```
public class Event {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer price;
    private Rating rating;

    private Set<Calendar> eventDateTime;
```

I can not find how to get all `dateTimes` for everyone event. Here is what I have so far:

```
public Set<Event> getForDateRange(Calendar from, Calendar to) {
    Set<Event> result = Collections.emptySet();
    Set<Event> allEvents = getAll();
    for (Event event : allEvents) {
        Set<Calendar> eventDateTime = event.getEventDateTime();
        result.addAll(eventDateTime.stream()
                .filter(date -> date.after(from) && date.before(to))
                .map(date -> event)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am using the mixture of iterative style with functional. How to write this method using functional style only?

Comment: `.map(date -> event)` does not really make sense. Could you explain in English what you want to do?

Comment: He wants to get all `Event`s within a date range `from`-`to` using functional programming code only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is a bit weird: `.map(date -> event)` is mapping for all dates the same event.

What you want is to retain all events such that one of the event time is between `from` and `to`. You can obtain that with [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-). This operation returns whether any of the stream element matches the given predicate. In this case, if any dates are between `from` and `to`, we keep the event and collect that into a `Set`.

```
public Set<Event> getForDateRange(Calendar from, Calendar to) {
    Set<Event> allEvents = getAll();

    return allEvents.stream()
            .filter(event -> event.getEventDateTime()
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(date -> date.after(from) && date.before(to))
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: Yes, `anyMatch()` is much better

Comment: @Tunaki good solution. I stacked with getting the second stream for Set.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do this in one-line in functional style:

```
    Set<Event> result = allEvents.stream().
            filter(
                    event -> !event.getEventDateTime().
                            stream().
                            filter(date -> date.after(from) && date.before(to)).collect(Collectors.toSet())
                            .isEmpty()
            ).
            collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

**UPD:** where `filter(date -> date.after(from) && date.before(to)).collect(Collectors.toSet())
                            .isEmpty()` can be replaced with @Tunaki's solution with `anyMatch(...)` which is much better.